# ngRepeat: Dupes when posting data with angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am working on submitting a form to a query on a php page and returning a table of data. If I don't submit parameters, this works great.  However if I try to add parameters to the post (to be used in the query), I receive an ngRepeat:Dupes error.

Any ideas as to what could cause this? Still relatively new to angular

```js
$http.post(url ,// Application module
var reportRequest = angular.module('reportRequest',[]);

reportRequest.controller('reportRequest', function($scope, $http) {

    // create a blank object to handle form data.
    $scope.report = {};

    // calling our submit function.
    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        // Posting data to php file    
        $http.post(url, {
            "selectPerson" : $scope.report.firstname
        }).success(function(data){
            // Stored the returned data into scope 
            $scope.people= data;
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="person in people track by $index | filter:search_query">
<td><span>{{person.firstname}}</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: When you are posting the data? I mean the event.

Comment: Can you post more code or plunker.

Comment: The function is being called onClick of a button

Comment: Usually this error occurs when you are having duplicate data in your loop.

Also,I was having issues when used track by index ahead of filters.. Try <tr ng-repeat="person in people | filter:search_query track by $index">

Comment: That did fix my dupes error.  I am now getting a table but with no data displaying..I can log the data now though...Any thoughts as to why the data would not display?  Keep in mind, if I remove the post parameters, it works

Comment: A Plunker would be helpful. One thing is your filter, if search_query variable is undefined than the filter would try to compare every object with your undefined value, hence will return nothing after filteration.. also if you want to put filter on one object property do it like this filter:{'firstname':search_query}

Answer (score 0):

Track by has to be always at the end of your ng-repeat.

Change this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in people track by $index | filter:search_query">
```

To this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in people | filter:search_query track by $index">
```

Then about data not shown sending the post data, this seems to be wrong, even if this part of code is missing and would be nice if you can show us what's happening:

```
{"selectPerson":$scope.report.firstname}
```

The report object is empty and then you try to send the property `firstname` of report on submit.
But are you sure that this property is actually there in this way? And not something like `$scope.report.person.firstname`?
Maybe you can add a console.log() before the POST request to see how actually how your report object looks like.

```
console.log($scope.report);
$http.post(url ,{"selectPerson":$scope.report.firstname}).success(function(data){
          // Stored the returned data into scope 
          $scope.people= data;
         console.log(data);
      });
```

I hope this helps